# Solve implicit complicated equation

Tags: equation-solving, implicit

I have to solve the following implicit equation:

```
1/Sqrt[16 π^4 + 8 π^2 y^2 + y^4 - 
   4 y^2 x^2] (Sqrt[16 π^4 + 8 π^2 y^2 + y^4 - 4 y^2 x^2] - 
    Sqrt[16 π^4 + 8 π^2 y^2 + y^4 - 4 y^2 x^2]
      Cos[1/2 Sqrt[4 π^2 + y^2 - 2 y x]] Cos[
      1/2 Sqrt[4 π^2 + y^2 + 2 y x]] + (4 π^2 + y^2 - 
       2 x^2) Sin[1/2 Sqrt[4 π^2 + y^2 - 2 y x]] Sin[
      1/2 Sqrt[4 π^2 + y^2 + 2 y x]])==0
```

I am trying :

```
f[x_, y_] := 
 1/Sqrt[16 π^4 + 8 π^2 y^2 + y^4 - 
    4 y^2 x^2] (Sqrt[16 π^4 + 8 π^2 y^2 + y^4 - 4 y^2 x^2] - 
     Sqrt[16 π^4 + 8 π^2 y^2 + y^4 - 4 y^2 x^2]
       Cos[1/2 Sqrt[4 π^2 + y^2 - 2 y x]] Cos[
       1/2 Sqrt[4 π^2 + y^2 + 2 y x]] + (4 π^2 + y^2 - 
        2 x^2) Sin[1/2 Sqrt[4 π^2 + y^2 - 2 y x]] Sin[
       1/2 Sqrt[4 π^2 + y^2 + 2 y x]])
g[x_, y_] := 
 Assuming[{{x, y} ∈ Reals, x >= 2 π}, Simplify[f[x, y]]]
Solve[g[x, y] == 0, {y}]
```

I receive the message: Solve: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.

What's wrong? Any suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately, as the [docs state](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html), "`Solve` deals primarily with linear and polynomial equations". As written, your equation may simply be more than `Solve` can handle. If you can work with a numerical solution, then look into [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html).

Comment: Also, are you sure that you want to solve only for $y$? Any solution would be expressed as a function of $x$ then. Are you trying to find an explicit expression for $y=f(x)$? There may not be one.

Comment: There seems to be an extra conditional `==` in `f[x,y]`.

Comment: yes i want an explicit expression for y=f(x), is there a solution?

Comment: It seems highly unlikely that such a complicated expression has an analytic solution.

Comment: So can I determine a numerical solution for x in the interval [0,24] ?

Comment: One can use `NDSolve` to get parametrized branches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little bit of thought + *Mathematica* reveals a few symmetric solutions:

```
eqn =(*1/Sqrt[16 π^4+8 π^2 y^2+y^4-4 y^2 x^2] *)
  (Sqrt[16 π^4 + 8 π^2 y^2 + y^4 - 4 y^2 x^2] - 
     Sqrt[16 π^4 + 8 π^2 y^2 + y^4 - 4 y^2 x^2] Cos[1/2 Sqrt[4 π^2 + y^2 - 2 y x]] *
        Cos[1/2 Sqrt[4 π^2 + y^2 + 2 y x]] +
   (4 π^2 + y^2 - 2 x^2) Sin[1/2 Sqrt[4 π^2 + y^2 - 2 y x]] *
        Sin[1/2 Sqrt[4 π^2 + y^2 + 2 y x]]) == 0;

DeleteDuplicates@Cases[eqn, Sqrt[_], Infinity];
sub = Thread[% -> {u v, u, v}];

Subtract @@ eqn /. sub // Simplify
(*  u v - u v Cos[u/2] Cos[v/2] + (4 π^2 - 2 x^2 + y^2) Sin[u/2] Sin[v/2]  *)

sub2 = {u/2 + v/2 -> P, u/2 - v/2 -> Q, u v -> P^2 - Q^2,
   y^2 -> P^2 + Q^2 - 4 Pi^2, y^2 + 4 Pi^2 -> P^2 + Q^2,
   x^2 -> (P Q)^2/(P^2 + Q^2 - 4 Pi^2)};

(* the form of the u,v equation above can be simplified thus, to show symmetry *)
A - A Cos[b] Cos[c] + B Sin[b] Sin[c] // TrigReduce // 
 Collect[#, {Cos[b - c], Cos[b + c]}] &
% /. {A -> u v, B -> (4 π^2 - 2 x^2 + y^2), b -> u/2, c -> v/2} //. sub2
(*
  A + 1/2 (-A + B) Cos[b - c] + 1/2 (-A - B) Cos[b + c]

  P^2 - Q^2 + 
   1/2 (-2 P^2 + (2 P^2 Q^2)/(P^2 - 4 π^2 + Q^2)) Cos[P] + 
   1/2 (2 Q^2 - (2 P^2 Q^2)/(P^2 - 4 π^2 + Q^2)) Cos[Q]
*)
```

This last result represents an equation symmetric with respect to `P ↔ Q`, `P ↔ -P` and `Q ↔ -Q`. One can also see that `y == 0` is a solution by inspection.  This leads to the following:

```
(* P^2 == Q^2 by even symmetry of preceding result *)
eqnPQ = P^2 == Q^2 /. Reverse /@ sub2 /. Reverse /@ sub;
sol1 = Append[Solve[eqnPQ, y], {y -> 0}]
eqn /. % // Simplify
(* 5 solutions:
   {{y -> -x - Sqrt[-4 π^2 + x^2]}, {y ->  x - Sqrt[-4 π^2 + x^2]},
    {y -> -x + Sqrt[-4 π^2 + x^2]}, {y -> x + Sqrt[-4 π^2 + x^2]},
    {y -> 0}}
   {True, True, True, True, True}    <-- verification
*)

Plot[y /. sol1 // Evaluate, {x, -6 Pi, 6 Pi}, PlotRange -> 6 Pi, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The red wedges below suggest there are more solutions. The white regions are where the square roots are imaginary.

```
ContourPlot[
 Subtract @@ eqn // Evaluate,
 {x, -6 Pi, 6 Pi}, {y, -6 Pi, 6 Pi},
 Contours -> {-100, 0, 100, 400},
 ContourShading -> {Black, Red, Blue, Lighter[Blue, 0.33], Lighter[Blue, 0.67]},
 MaxRecursion -> 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]